# Why is my Graph.Users.MailFolders request suddenly throwing a 400 error?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server

I have some code that was working before the weekend, and now on Monday it is throwing an exception whenever I call Graph.Users["user id here"].MailFolders

The error is 400 AuthenticationError: Error authenticating with resource

The application has an app registration in my tenant that has Mail.Read and User.Read.All application permissions. It is authenticating using client secret authentication.

So far I have tried deleting and recreating the app registration, but the behavior did not change.

Comment: Hi @Jan Martin, can you please provide which query your using and the query error details with Client ID, request ID and timestamp of it.

Comment: I am using the Graph SDK, I am not sure what the query is, but the code is

```Graph.Users[user.Id].MailFolders.Request().GetAsync().Result;```

{AdditionalData:
 date: 2022-06-07T06:26:36
 request-id: d3a18a7c-0fc5-49a3-b10e-dcfb7a1088a3
 client-request-id: d3a18a7c-0fc5-49a3-b10e-dcfb7a1088a3
}

Comment: I checked the Graph logs looks like we are getting 0 as response this might also be result of the user may not have mail folder which might result in this error.

Comment: I am getting the error for users who I know don't have a mailbox, and users who I know do have a mailbox